# Form Builder with Query Builder cannot access property on Join

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form builder where I am generating a select option. In this select I have to take out the elements that already exist in the database. For this I am creating a query builder.
Now in this query builder I want to make a `JOIN` to get a single row from the languages table for a specific language.
The problem is that after I added this `JOIN` symfony returns an access error:

> Error: Cannot access private property 
>   XXX\DatabaseBundle\Entity\AttributeGroupLanguage::$id

Here is what I do:

```
$builder->add('attributeGroups', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'XXX\DatabaseBundle\Entity\AttributeGroup',
    'choice_label' => 'name',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($existingAttributeGroups) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('ag')
                  ->addSelect('agl')
                  ->join('XXXDatabaseBundle:AttributeGroupLanguage agl', 'WITH agl.attributeGroup = ag.id')
                  ->where('ag.id NOT IN (:existingAttributeGroups)')
                  ->andWhere('agl.language = :languageId')
                  ->setParameters(
                      array(
                          'existingAttributeGroups' => ($existingAttributeGroups) ?: '',
                          'languageId' => 1 //german
                      )
                  );
    },
    'attr' => array(
        'class' => 'attributeGroupsList',
        'style' => 'width: 250px'
    )
));
```

Comment: Looking at the error reported, you probably should add a getter method to AttributeGroupLanguage for $id property.

Answer (score 0):

Add public getId() method to AttributeGroupLanguage entity.

```
public function getId(){
    return $this->id;
}
```

Comment: I have all the getters and setter set up corectly

Comment: Not the right answer but, what I would do: I tend to avoid as much as possible to use 'entity' type. I keep model and repositories logic away from user interface (presentation) layer. I would make that a 'choice' type, and I would add service method that retrieves and formats data to supply 'choices' option.

Comment: I end up making a new function and not use entity anymore but simple choice and the result of the function is the choice array. Still waiting maybe someone has an idea what to do here...